# FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm using javamail 1.5.5 and I want to listen for new messages in a GMail mailbox.

I have an implementation of MessageCountListener, on its messagesAdded method, at the end I do:

```
try {
        // process new messages
        idleManager.watch(ifo); // keep watching for new messages
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        logger.error(".....", mex);
    }
```

I'm not sure to understand because I get that exception...

I believe that I'm doing what said here https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html#watch-javax.mail.Folder-

Follows some mail debug log, consider that after that exception, no new messages arrived anymore to the listner.

```
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imaps://xxxxxxxxxx@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX
* 1026 FETCH (UID 4284 FLAGS (\Answered \Seen))
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager continue watching folder imaps://xxxxxxx@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager adding imaps://xxxxxxxxx@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX to selector
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected 1 channels
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager selected folder: imaps://xxxxxxxxxxx@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX
DEBUG IMAP: handleIdle: set to RUNNING
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager got exception for folder: imaps://prismatest@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX, THROW: 
javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3199)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IdleManager.processKeys(IdleManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IdleManager.select(IdleManager.java:281)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IdleManager.access$200(IdleManager.java:137)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IdleManager$1.run(IdleManager.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
DEBUG IMAP: IdleManager waiting...
```

Thanks, bye

Comment: How long was it from when you started watching the folder to when the connection was dropped?  If the connection remains unused for 30 minutes or so, the server might drop the connection.

Comment: Yes @Bill, more or less 30 minutes I'm quite sure.
Thanks for your reply, I've read other your answers here on stackoverflow, thank you very much but in my humble opinion it is not so clear how to to such a task.
In your opinion the monitor.java sample contained in javamail-sample may be a good starting point?

Comment: May I ask you why one should prefer IdleManager to folder.idle (as used in monitor.java of javamail-sample) ? 
Furthermore in IdleManager documentation there is a note telling that it is an EXPERIMENTAL api (in bold), so where is the advantages  in your opinion? Thanks

Comment: IdleManager is intended for the case where you need to monitor multiple folders and don't want to dedicate a thread to each folder.  Using the idle method on a specific folder ties up the calling thread while waiting for notifications.  The monitor.java sample program handles only the simple case.  With either the IdleManager or idle method approaches, you'll still need another thread that periodically "pokes" the server to keep the connection alive (e.g., by calling Folder.getMessageCount).  And you always have to handle the case where the connection breaks unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks Bill.
Why another thread?
Could be enough catching ""javax.mail.FolderClosedException: Lost folder connection to server" and reopone it inside the loop in thread doing idle?

Comment: My previous comment was inspired by spring-ws, see the example 3 here http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.mail.FolderClosedException

Comment: If the server just drops the connection without sending the BYE response, you'll never get a notification that the connection has been closed until you do something to actively use the connection.  That's why you need to poke it once in awhile.

Comment: @Gamby were you able to  fix it ?

Comment: Yes @VGH, you have to follow hints above

Comment: @Gamby can you please provide full working code here as an answer?

Comment: No I can't, I'm sorry