# javax.mail.Store needs to be closed?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a small server-like application which can be configurable with many email accounts, and for each of them it sets listner to be notified about either added messages or removed.

I wasn't able to find if I should connect and disconnect to store each time for example I do:

```
store.getDefaultFolder().getFolder(folderName);
```

or

```
store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
```

For what I undestood I could connect to store only the first time I need it and then leave it open untill application is being stopped, what do you think?
Thanks, bye

Comment: The mail server is very likely to drop a long-running connection on you anyway. You can try to persist it but you need to cope with drops.

Comment: And in fact the connection can be closed without you ever being notified.  You need to "poke" the connection every 30 minutes or so to make sure it's still alive.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes Bill I do it with the "two threads" technique already discussed here too.

With this question I wanted strictly only know how to properly handle store connection and disconnection, so which should be the best practice in your opinion?

Comment: Have you solved it? Might want to look into webhooks vs long-polling.

Comment: @parsecer I do only one connect when my application starts, handling disconnections trying reconnecting to Store. To keep alive the connection take a look to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252891/folderclosedexception-bye-javamail-exception-java-io-ioexception-connection